# How to view media queries with Google chrome dev tool or Firefox dev tool?

Tags: css, media-queries

How can I view media queries that affect elements on a responsive bootstrap menu?

The menu doesn't display under 950px, if I can find the media query and play with it I can make it visible, but can't see it.

Site is here:

http://www.longislandpartypeople.com/

Comment: The menu doesn't display because of this rule: @media (max-width: 950px){
.main-menu {
    display: none;
}} which is in your style.css at line 743

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Chrome Dev Tools has some great features built in to their responsive testing (the mobile icon at the top left of Dev Tools).

[image]

One of these is viewing a [graphical representation of all media queries](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/device-mode/emulate-mobile-viewports#optional_controls_eg_touch_media_queries_dpr). It can be enabled by clicking on the vertical ellipses, and selecting "Show Media Queries". From there, you'll be able to see all your current breakpoints. Finally, right-clicking on the breakpoint where you notice your change (as you resize the responsive window) allows you to see the source CSS for that query, using "Reveal in source code".

In your case, clicking on the media query for `(max-width: 950px)` brings you to the following place in your source code:

```
@media all and ( max-width: 950px ) {
.mobile-button { display:block; }
.main-menu { display:none; }
.photo-slider { height:300px; }
.top-wrapper .slider .center-wrapper { left:80px; right:80px; bottom:150px !important;  }
.top-wrapper h1 { line-height:52px; }
}
```

Where `.main-menu` is being set to `display:none`. Dev tools will also show you the line of the source code; in this case, line 743 (just as [Jonas Giuro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254917/jonas-giuro) pointed out in his comment).

Comment: " It can be enabled by clicking on the vertical ellipses, and selecting "Show Media Queries" , I can't find that setting, what do you mean be vertical elipse? Additionally any good tutorials or manual on how to use Chrome dev tool? Documentation not for advanced devs? Thanks

Comment: No problem - here's an [image](http://imgur.com/Re7py0v) showing the button to enable responsive mode, highlighted in yellow, and the vertical ellipses, circled in blue. Then when you click that ellipses, you can choose "Show Media Queries" from [this dropdown](http://imgur.com/PojZAQO). I also took a look to see if I could find any tutorials, but in this case, the direct Google docs really seem to be the best. [Here's](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/) a great, simple place to start.

Comment: Additionally, do you know why it's not displaying the mobile menu? I know the main must be hidden, but I wonder why the mobile is not displaying under 950 px...I may open a new post?

Comment: Sure. For reference, the best way to find these things is to look at elements that you *expect* to change with media queries, and watch their styles change as you resize.
In this case, you have [2 issues](http://imgur.com/ZA0DQ5q): your media query isn't specific enough at 950px for the `.mobile-button`, so it gets overridden by the original `display: none`. And there's no content in your `<span>` for the button.

[Here it is fixed](http://imgur.com/QDxEadq). Notice the more specific media query, and the value "i" for Entypo. You'll still need to adjust `z-index` for `.mobile-button` :)

Comment: Thanks Jack, I really appreciate this...but still I'm struggling...could you post the whole CSS file on codepen and I can paste it in? Then I can look at the code and see the changes with file side by side? I've added the i to the span in the HTML, but I can't seem to get the css right, not sure what to take out or add, and I'm weak on specificity, not asking you to hold my hand, if you can't that's ok also;)

Comment: Yeah - [these](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GWmmdO) are the temporary changes I was trying out on Dev Tools to `style.css` (`z-index` changed on line 306, and more specific query on line 742). Definitely keep playing around, and probably good to create another question for any other issues.

Comment: Thanks Jack. This website is a pain in the ass, don't you agree? How should I go about charging my client for this? Every change I make everything cascades down to problems, it's like fixing something with clamps and masking tape...how do you handle projects like this? This is NOT something I built!

Answer (score 0):

When the style is being applied, the media query is displayed in the elements styles in dev tools

Here is your offending setting:

[image]